# Some mobile phone report "Scan Failed" Error when two or more iBeacon transmitter, how can i figure out these phones?

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

When I use HUAWEI 7i mobile phone to range two beacon transmitters with "didRangeBeaconsInRegion" callback function, the code reports:

```
E/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(11734): Scan Failed error.
```

When I use Nexus 5, it's OK and returns back two beacon information packets.

Is there any method that can solve this error? 
If not, how can I figure out this kind of mobile phone in code? 
Is there any code like:

```
BeaconTransmitter.checkTransmissionSupported(context)
```

To check whether this mobile phone can ring two or more beacon signals or not?

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:    --Update on 31st Aug**

I tried three mobile phone with this code, the result is as following:

*HuaWei 7i with Android 5.1.1:*
more than one transmitter will cause **Scan Failed** error;

*HuaWei P8 with Android 6.0:*
more than one transmitter will return **only one** beacon package;

*Nexus 5 with Android 5.1.1:*
more than one transmitter will **all beacon package correctly**.

I'm totally confused by these phenomenons...

Comment: It seems a issue on Lollipop. See [Link](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/289)

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

- You can call `bluetoothAdapter.isMultipleAdvertisementSupported()` to see if a specific Android device allows transmitting more than one advertisement at a time.  Some devices do, some do not.
- If the call above returns false, it may mean that advertising is not supported at all (e.g. Nexus 5) or only one advertisement may be sent (e.g. Moto X).
- Even if multiple advertisements are supported, there are a limited number of slots, and other apps may have used them all.  There is no way to tell how many slots are free.  If you cannot get a free slot, advertising will fail.
- The scan failure you report on the HuaWei 7i  when advertising sounds like a firmware bug specific to that device.  This is clearly not intended behavior and I have not seen it on other devices.  Your best bet may be to detect this device type and disallow transmitting and scanning at the same time on your app.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm sorry for my poor English. It seems you misunderstand my meaning. My question is how can I figure out those mobile phones which can't ranging more than one iBeacon transmitters. The iBeacon transmitters are not mobile phone itself, just other iBeacon station, for example arduino+HM10. With Nexus 5 mobile phone, I can rang all the iBeacon information came from several iBeacon stations. With HuaWei P8, I can only rang one iBeacon information. And with HuaWei 7i, it returns **E/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(11734): Scan Failed** error. Same code, same iBeacon stations.

Comment: I also installed Locate app on my HuaWei 7i mobile phone. When I pressed "Locate Beacons" button to range more than one iBeacon signal, the app will restart. If there's only one iBeacon station, the Locate app is OK and will return back the information of the iBeacon signal.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding.   My last point is still valid.  It sounds like there is a firmware problem on the HuaWei 7i that causes its bluetooth scanning to fail if more than one bluetooth device is visible.  This is not normal.  I don't think there is any way to know a list of devices that have firmware problems like this.  This is the first report I have heard, so I would simply detect this device and accept that beacon scanning is not available.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have another question, is it a similar issue like this?[Lollipop long period scan broke phone's Bluetooth](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/289). Because I have the same situation: when **Scan Failed** error reported, the only way out is restart the mobile phone. Otherwise, the code couldn't range iBeacon signal any more, even only one iBeacon station is on. The error is **E/CycledLeScannerForLollipop(11734): Scan Failed**

Comment: The symptom sounds similar -- essentially a crash of the Bluetooth stack requiring a restart to correct.  But the cause, as you describe it, is different.

Comment: OK, thanks for your explanation. I'm sure my description above is correct. If possible, hope you can get a HuaWei 7i mobile phone. Then you can try Locate app on it and check to rang several iBeacon stations. You'll see the app restarts. I'm sure of that.